# Wie sagt man "Cover album" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Die Beatles haben 15 Lieder für ihre Plattenhülle "Help" komponiert.

Ich weiß nicht, ob das richtige Wort für "*Cover album*" "*Plattenhülle*" ist.

> Ich habe viele Plattenhüllen der Beatles in meinem Schlafzimmer im
>   Regal stehen.

Comment: Schade ist es doch, wenn man nur die Plattenhüllen im Regal stehen hat - schöner wäre es doch, wenn man die Platten auch im Regal stehen hätte. Üblicherweise würde man doch daher sagen: *Ich habe viele Platten der Beatles ... im Regal stehen* und nicht nur die Plattenhüllen.

Comment: The [3rd revision](http://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/9987/3) changed the meaning of the question. The requestor was asking about how to translate *cover album* and not *album cover*. The edit should be reversed.

Comment: @falkb Ich habe deinen Edit rückgängig gemacht. Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen Albumcover und Coveralbum. In dem Kontext macht aber nur Coveralbum Sinn. Ein Coveralbum ist ein Album, welches aus Coversongs besteht und daher wurden 15 Lieder für das Coveralbum komponiert. Das Albumcover (welches jedes Album hat, nicht nur die Coveralben), besteht nicht aus Lieder und stehen auch nicht im Regal.

Comment: @SentryRaven: No, looking at the two example sentences he wants to have a translation for jewel case or record sleeve, respectively. Unfortunately, his German and English wording is wrong.

Comment: In case of "Cover album" he should fix his confusing 2 example sentences

Comment: @falkb Warum komponierst du Songs für das Deckblatt? – Ersetze in beiden Sätzen "Plattenhülle" mit "Album" und die Sätze sind zu 100% korrekt.

Comment: @Em1: dann will er wohl wahrscheinlich eigentlich nicht wissen, was "Coveralbum" oder "Plattenhülle" heißt, sondern er sucht einfach eine Übersetzung für "Album". Man sollte also das "Cover" aus der Frage nehmen.

Comment: Das ist reine Spekulation, das müsste @DerPoly uns dann selbst mitteilen, ob er *Album*, *Cover-Album* oder *Plattenhülle* meinte.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Please, enlight us what you actually mean!: album, cover album, record sleeve or jewel case? The 2 examples look like simply *album*. Then we could remove the whole spam of comments here again. :-D

Comment: Also Plattenhülle meinte er mit Sicherheit nicht. Wenn überhaupt meinte er "nur" Album, aber ich denke wirklich das "Cover album" schon die Intention ist, nur sie erklärt, warum über die Verwechslung mit Plattenhülle aufkommen kann.

Comment: Falkb : i wanted to say " The Beatles composed 15 songs for the álbum album "Help " "

Comment: In which case you created your own confusion, trying to translate cover album before trying to translate album. Whatever media you used to translate *cover album* got it wrong and tried to translate *album cover*, which resulted in *Plattenhülle*. That however would be a record sleeve, as @falk indicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plattenhülle would be "album cover". I would translate "cover album" with "Cover-Album". ([Wikipedia: Cover-Album](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover-Album), [Duden: Coverversion](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Coverversion))

Comment: Man darf sich auch langsam trauen, es Coveralbum zu schreiben. Das Wort Cover ist für eine Neuauflage eines Songs aber definitiv eingedeutscht und daher richtig (+1). Coverversion ist natürlich etwas anderes, und betrifft nur einen einzelnen Track, während das Coveralbum das ganze Album betitelt.

Answer (score 3):

Der reinen Vollständigkeit halber hier noch die Sätze aus der Frage in korrekter Fassung, wobei an Stelle von `Album` umgangssprachlich auch `Platte` verwendet werden kann, dies gilt im Allgemeinen nicht nur für Schallplatten sondern gleichermaßen auch für CDs.

> Die Beatles haben 15 Lieder für <del>ihre Plattenhülle</del> **ihr Album** „Help“ komponiert.

> Ich habe viele <del>Plattenhüllen</del> **Alben** der Beatles in meinem Schlafzimmer im Regal stehen.

Comment: Genau, denn sie haben die Lieder ja nicht für ihr "cover album" kompiniert, sonder für das Original.

Comment: @Ingo Aber das Original ist doch das Coveralbum!

Comment: @Em1 Moment. Ein Coveralbu8m ist ein Album, das Coversongs, oder Coverversionen enthät, richtig? Und letztere sind definiert "In popular music, a cover version or cover song, or simply cover, is a new performance or recording of a contemporary or previously recorded, commercially released song". Somit müssen die Songs schon komponiert gewesen sein.

Comment: @Ingo Soweit richtig. Deswegen sage ich ja, dass das Original das Coveralbum ist. Ein Coveralbum hat den Unterschied zu einem normalen Album, dass die Songs alle schon mal existiert und neuaufgelegt worden sind. Insofern sind alle Songs nur Covers, welche aber in ihrer Form wiederum original sind, da sie ja neu komponiert sind. Somit ist ein jedes Coveralbum eigentlich nur ein Album, es sei denn, du willst explizit darauf hinweisen, dass alle Songs gecovert sind, dann sagst du Coveralbum ;)

Comment: @Em1 - Du kannst einen Song neu interpretieren, arrangieren, instrumentieren, aber sicher nicht neu komponieren. Letzteres wäre höchstens dann möglich, wenn jemand, der nachweislich noch nie "Help" gehört haben kann, sich hinsetzt und ein Lied schreibt, und es sich dann herausstellt, daß es identisch mit "Help" ist.

Comment: @Ingo Ok. Ungünstige Wortwahl. Natürlich meinte ich nicht "neu komponieren". Aber die Grundaussage bleibt bestehen ;)